# Tagging each player's touches in a soccer game

Tags: editing

I'm a soccer coach and I'm always looking for ways to help my players improve. For example, we record all of our games so the players can watch them afterwards. However, I find it to be an inefficient use of time for a player to watch the entire game if they only touch the ball 17 times, for example.

My question:  is there a way for me to tag every time each player touches the ball? Then when a player reviews the video, after I finish this editing run, they can pull up the 17 times that I've tagged them? I'm open to using whatever software and process would best meet my need.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: A hack solution might be to upload it to YouTube. Then in a comment under the video you can just write the time that a player touches. The youtube engine will automatically turn it into a link that will reload the video to that time.

Answer (score 1):

My solution here is time- and labor- intensive, but it will work. I'm tailoring it for Adobe Premiere, since that's what I use, but any multi-track editing software should be able to handle this.

The person editing the video brings the footage of the game (which I'll call the "main video") into the timeline. Then the editor adds a new video track for each player who was in the game.

The editor watches the video of the game (the "main video"), and each time a particular player touches the ball, the editor

- cuts the main video before and after that touch
- copies that clip from the main video
- pastes it onto the track for that player

[image]

If two players are touching the ball simultaneously for some reason, the clip gets pasted into both their timelines.

After the whole main video has been "distributed" this way, there will be big gaps between the clips in each players' timeline. The editor now removes the gaps from each timeline.

The editor then hides all tracks except player #1, sets the correct endpoint of the video (for that track), and exports that as its own video. The file name for the export can be that player's name. The editor then hides player #1, and displays player #2, sets the video endpoint, and exports again.

This whole process is somewhat tedious, but it will work. I'll be interested to read other people's ideas!

Comment: Hi Brett, thanks for the detailed response. I was waiting to see if we'd get any other responses before adding this comment. While I'm glad to see that you've come up with a functional plan, I agree that it sounds laborious. I was hoping there might be a simpler way to tag the times that each player touched the ball but life doesn't always give us what we want :). THANK YOU again for your response.  -Adam

Answer (score -1):

hey i maybe came up with a better solution : 
upload it to youtube and provide your players with the timesatmps in the description this way they can click on it and see their stuff

Comment: This is a totally legitimate answer, but it's not written in the style and form of a proper answer on StackExchange (hence the negative vote).